In GraphQL schema definition, does it make sense to have an union of objects already in a common interface?
my question is more about general GraphQL schema definition conventions to build a well designed schema rather than a question about the difference between union/interface.
Let's say I have the following type definitions in GQL :
interface Animal {
   move: String
}

type Dog implements Animal {
   move: String
   height: Int 
}

type Cat implements Animal {
   move: String
   jumpHeight: Int
}

union availableAnimals = Dog | Cat

type Spot {
   animal: availableAnimals
}

Does it make sense that I created an union and put it as type in Spot ? I could have simply put the interface Animal instead. However, as I know this API will likely change a lot and don't want to introduce breaking changes, I like that I can keep making the schema evolve without exposing the new Animals in the Spot yet(even if it's not what I intend to do).
Also by having an union instead of an interface, I force the client to resolve a specific animal as I think it makes no sense in my schema to only resolve the common field between animals, is it a valid concern or is it more standard to let the client completely decides what he wants to do ?
From the client-side, a client may want to display the list of all the different animals in a table and the day this API returns a new animal, their UI will not list the new Animal as it will be filtered by GQL as not requested by fragments. If I keep an interface, that table would have columns filled only for the common field and a "detailed" view would show nothing else than these common fields too. Unexpected new Animals are maybe a bad thing as that front-end may not know what to do/display in the meantime until it's updated to properly process them. With an union, the client purposely have to write the code dedicated to process the new Animal type and nothing changes until it is done.
Of course that front-end could take precautionary measures and not display whatever is returned by that API but doesn't that make the union better in that, this issue would never happen?
Moreover, the client may not fully know GQL and always request the move field for each Animal (if the type was an interface) which causes a lot of internal DB/ 3rd party API queries but if he had to purposely specify it for each Animal, he would think more and only request that field for the only Animal he needs. Of course this does not protect against any kind of purposeful abuse but it's still better than nothing? To me, it makes the schema more expressive but it's more restrictive

If you have no intention to have several unions with different animals (e.g. DomesticAnimals and WildAnimals) then there is no real point to have both. Interface is preferable since any code working with it will work with new animals.
Animal types not specified when requesting a union will not be filtered. You'll just get their __typename with no other fields. Querying a union without __typename field does not make sense to me. Most clients add this field automatically.
I do not see any reason to be picky about the move field for a list of animals. You either need it for every animal or for none of them.
